# How to create object of CustomTextView class

Tags: android, textview, android-canvas

how to create an object of the class, and provide value to constructor like AttributeSet etc. and also setText("")

```
public class CustomTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

   public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint2 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        textPaint.setTextSize(getTextSize());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
       // ..........
    }
}
```

// how to use in java

```
CustomTextView cTV = new CustomTextView (...........)??
cTV.setText("how to create like that");
```

Comment: you want to create a new `CustomTextView` object from your java code? or xml layout?

Comment: there is a complete guide for custom Views at the developer.android.com see https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Having this kind of constructor means, that are able to use this custom view from `xml` layout, no direct way to dynamically create through java code.

Comment: yes @pskink i want to  create object in java

Comment: see `View(Context)` constructor then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just create Constructor for CustomTextView Class

```
 public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);

 }
```

Now we can easily access any properties of CustomTextView Class.

Answer (score 2):

first of all you need to define the class.

```
public class CustomFontTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

private static final String CUSTOM_FONT = "cfont";
private static final String FONT_PATH = "fonts/";

private String ttfName;
private Typeface font;
private CharSequence text;
private BufferType type;

public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs);
}


private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    this.ttfName = attrs.getAttributeValue(AppConstants.NAMESPACE, CUSTOM_FONT);

    if (ttfName.startsWith("@string/") || ttfName.startsWith("@")) {
        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomFontTextView);
        this.ttfName = ta.getString(R.styleable.CustomFontTextView_cfont);
        ta.recycle();
    }

    this.setPaintFlags(this.getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);

    try {
        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT_PATH + ttfName);
        setTypeface(font);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        font = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL);
        setTypeface(font);
    }

    setText(text, type);
}


@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    try {
        this.text = text;
        this.type = type;
        if (font == null)
            return;

        CustomFontStyling customFontStyling = new CustomFontStyling(getContext(), font);
        super.setText(customFontStyling.getCustomText(text.toString()), type);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

After you need to add the styleable in your attrs.xml

```
 <declare-styleable name="CustomFontTextView">
    <attr name="cfont" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And finally on your xml layout

```
 <YOURAPPPACKAGE.CustomFontTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cfont="@string/open_sans_regular" />
```

Comment: This is java! please explain what do you mean!